# sed: Why does "s/TR[0-9]*//2g" work but not "s/TR[0-9].*//2g"?

Tags: regex, sed

My file look like this:

```
>TR45672|c1_g1_i1|m.87632TR21000
sometextherethatmayincludeTRbutnonumbers
>TR10000|c0_g1_i1|m.83558TR1702000
sometextherethatmayincludeTRbutnonumbers
....
....
```

I want it to looks like this:

```
>TR45672|c1_g1_i1|m.87632
sometextherethatmayincludeTRbutnonumbers
>TR10000|c0_g1_i1|m.83558
sometextherethatmayincludeTRbutnonumbers
....
....
```

In other words, I want to remove second occurrence of the pattern TR in the headers (rows that start with ">") and everything after that, but not touch any TR patterns in lines that are not headers. In non-header lines, TR will never ever be followed by a number.

I try to use the following code:

```
sed "s/TR[0-9].*//2g"
```

It will, as I have understood it, match TR and then a number and remove all instances but the first one. Since there are always exactly two occurrences of TR[0-9] in the header and no occurrences of TR[0-9] in non-headers, this will accomplish my goals...

...or so I thought. In reality, using the above code has no effect whatsoever.

If I instead skip the dot and use:

```
sed "s/TR[0-9]*//2g"
```

It produces what looks like the desired result for those lines I have manually checked.

Questions:

(1) How come it works without the dot but not work with it? My understanding is that ".*" is the key to removing everything after a pattern.

(2) Removing the dot seems to work, but it is not possible for me to manually check through the entire file. Is there are reason to suspect something unexpected happens when skipping the dot in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed "s/TR[0-9].*//2g"
```

...matches *the whole line from the first TR to the end of the line*, which means there is no following match (there's nothing left of the line to match since it has all been matched)

```
sed "s/TR[0-9]*//2g"
```

...first matches only the first `TR<number>` sequence, then finds the second match in the rest of the line.

Comment: So in other words, `sed "s/TR[0-9]*//2g"` is the legit way to do it in this case? Just so I'm on the same page as you.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: i'm too slow, the next time i'll skip ascii schemas :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Analyze the first line of your input file against the regex with the dot:

   ```
   |--------------------------------  (1) TR matches 'TR' literally
   |  |------------------------------ (2) [0-9] match a single digit
   |  | |---------------------------- (3) .* matches any char till the end
   |  | |
   TR 4 5672|c1_g1_i1|m.87632TR21000
   11 2 3333333333333333333333333333
   ---------------------------------
   1st and only match  so there no 2nd match or above to replace
   ```

So using `TR[0-9].*` you have a **single** match per line starting with `TR`.

2. If you use the second regex instead:

   ```
   |---------------------------------- (m1) TR matches 'TR' literally
   |  |------------------------------- (m1) [0-9]* match zero or more digits
   |  | 
   |  |                        |------ (m2) TR matches 'TR' literally
   |  |                        |  |--- (m2) [0-9]* match zero or more  
   TR 45672  |c1_g1_i1|m.87632 TR 21000
   --------                    --------
   1st match                   2nd match
   ```

By the way, since there are only two `TR` section you can skip `global` flag and use:

```
sed 's/TR[0-9]*//2' file
```